How can I reinstall a window sash dislocated by force?
I have a couple of big stationary floor-to-ceiling windows by the front door of my house.
Today I get a call that our dog went nuts over something in the front yard, pounded on the window, and managed to pop it out of the frame. It isn't broken, just not fully in the frame any more.
I'm wondering if this is a relatively simple fix that I might be able to do myself to pop that thing back in.
(Top-down view from inside. It's open to the outside on the right.)

(Head-on view from the inside. It's open to the outside on the right.)


It looks like a five minute job that will take at least five hours.  Window glass does not like pressure applied to it, and you would need levers applying pressure carefully to put it back.

@crip659 - Do you think heating the glass to make it more flexible (or perhaps cooling it to shrink it to lessen the pressure) would help? I've got some big hot/cold packs. Presumably somebody got it in there without breaking it in the first place.

No do not heat or cool, it will break

It was probably done when making the window.  The glass and the small amount of metal around it was place in the window frame or the window frame(on the wall) was built around it.  I second the comment about heat/cold placed on the window/glass.  Even stuff made for heat/cold do not like temperature changes

Your photos are far enough away and underexposed enough (for the black parts) that I can't really see what we're dealing with. Get close and get some light on the subject, please. Inside and out.

@isherwood - My daughter took those. I'm home today and went and took a couple with the flash on, but honestly I can't make out anything more looking at them than I can from the attached. Less really, although I will say with the flash its pretty clear I let things get unconscionably dirty down there.

Perhaps duct-taping across the glass while putting it back in might be a good idea to give it a wee bit more support?

Your first picture shows a screw at the center of the window frame at the bottom.
These window frames look like they are operating windows installed without operating hardware.
Remove any screws around the perimeter of the frame that are in the same position as that screw.
Remove the sash. Look for any spacers that were used to support the sash and reinstall.
Push the sash back into the frame.
Reapply the screws. If the screws do not hold, drill a new hole in a new location and install the screw.

Just did a quick once over now that I'm home. It looks like there are 2 screws on the bottom (as you can see in the picture) and 2 more on the top. None on the sides. I'll consider attacking it tomorrow when I have more time and light.

By "remove the sash", I assume you mean to remove it from the frame, not from the glass?

The Frame holds the sash. The Sash holds the glass.
